# How can I accurately search a directory with elements from a text file?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Fairly newish to python. I'm trying to use a list made from a text file to search directories for files and folders. Its working to certain extent but only if the search element is at the start of the file/folder name as I'm using .startswith().

The code I'm using is below.

I'm thinking regex might be the way to go but can't seem to figure it out.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

```
import os

def data_cleansing(path):

    dirscount = 0
    filescount = 0


    with open("Y:\Admin\Data Cleansing\DCList.txt","r") as f:
        x = f.readlines()
        x = [x.replace("\n","") for x in x]

    #print(x)


    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for dirs in dirs:
            if dirs.startswith(tuple(x)):
                dirscount = dirscount + 1
                #print(dirscount)
                print(os.path.join(dirs))



    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for files in files:
            if files.startswith(tuple(x)):
                filescount = filescount + 1
                #print(filescount)
                print(os.path.join(files))



    total = (dirscount + filescount)
    print(total,"files and folders found in",path,"that need cleansing.")

data_cleansing(r"G:\Processed\failed")
print("*"*70)
data_cleansing(r"G:\Processed\done")
print("*"*70)
data_cleansing(r"S:\Prosort")
print("*"*70)
data_cleansing(r"S:\Prosort_Archive")
```

Comment: If `.startswith()` doesn't work, don't use it. Did you try the [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) operator?

Comment: What are some inputs and their desired outputs according to your dilemma?

Comment: An element in the search list would be "MT19" and the directory to be searched has a folder called "MT19CORE" or XXXXMT19, Id like it if python could 'find' any instance of the "MT19". Thank you for the reply.

Comment: _I'm trying to use a list made from a text file to search directories for files and folders._ What do the list/file look like? See: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Does this fit your needs?

```
from os import scandir
find_list = ['Uni', '.doc', 'XML']
path = r"c:\\Autoit\\ForumTests\\"

def scantree(path):
    """Recursively yield DirEntry objects for given directory."""
    for entry in scandir(path):
        if entry.is_dir(follow_symlinks=False):
            yield from scantree(entry.path)
        else:
            yield entry

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for entry in scantree(path):
        for pattern in find_list:
            if pattern in entry.path:
                print(pattern, '-->', entry.path)
```